# Publish video on facebook page wall using graph api with no share button

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I tried earlier to publish video on Facebook page using Graph API without share button or link

**Old code:**

```
$data   =   array(
    'name'         =>   'name',
    'caption'      =>   'caption,
    'link'         =>   'http://link.com',
    'description'  =>   'description,
    'picture'   =>  '[picture url]',
    'source'    =>  '[video source]'                    
);

$result = $facebook->api('https://graph.facebook.com/[page_id]/feed?access_token=[page access token]',$data);
```

The above publication is treated earlier as post with video in it, but now its just treated as a link and the source video is not played in it. Same way we have 'share' link too.

Currently i required the publication to be treated as video + no share link.

I am unable to give empty "actions", whereas if i give "actions", the post has video played inline.

I want to know, how to publish video on page wall with no share button?